# Orchard :how to hide fields in content part by using placement.info?

Tags: orchardcms

I add one customer field called `WrapperSuppressed` into a widget content part. I can add and remove the wrapper for any widget. This boolean field is for management purpose, not for content. I'm trying to hide this filed in front end.

I put one line in placement.info, like this, which is working.:

```
<Place Fields_Boolean-WrapperSuppressed="-"/>
```

I need to add more condition, like the content part, which this field belong to, like this

```
<Place Fields_Boolean-WidgetPart-WrapperSuppressed="-"/>
```

This does not work.

Anyone can help  me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works: you can't just make up shape names like that. The first part of the attribute name has to be the shape name as emitted by the driver of the field (`Fields_Boolean` in your case), and the second is the name of the field. Do you have more than one field named `WrapperSuppressed` on any content type? If so, that's probably not such a good idea. There are other conditions that you can put into a `Match` tag surrounding the `Place`. You can match on content type, display type, and path. I recommend you read http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info for all the details.